# Do not show default value of the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have an input field

```
 <input id='spe_count' type="text" placeholder="number" class="form-control" data-original-title="" title="">
```

and as I need it to be by default with value -1 I am assigning it with jQuery

```
 $("#spe_count").val('-1');
```

And I get this input field and see this value -1 inside it, but what I want is that this input is with value -1, but on the page it would be empty or with placeholder.
And when I am changing values, I'd like to do so, that deleting value, emptying the box means that it is default value -1 (not typing minus one , but simply deleting all the values mean this is minus one)

Is this possible?

Comment: you can add an attribute to the <input> example <input type="text" data-value="-1"/>

Comment: simply set the value at the time of operation ans set placeholder to the filed by default.and when user enter any value in that field just calculate it with `-1`.

Comment: you can then work on the data-value by using the following $("#spe_count").attr("data-value");

Comment: When the form is submitted, you check value of this input. If it's empty then set its value = -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#("#spe_count").click(function(){
    var value= $(this).val();
    if(value.length < 1){
       $(this).attr("value", -1);
    }
});
```

The above code will serve your purpose.